# Why does the video-js endcard plugin add native controls to the player?

Tags: javascript, css, video.js

**Endcard** is a plugin for the [**video-js html5 video player**](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/) that inserts links at the end of a video. (Info on endcard: https://github.com/theonion/videojs-endcard). To insert an endcard, all you need is [videojs.endcard.js](http://www.casedasole.it/video/endcard/videojs.endcard.js), plus some css for styling.

But... problem is, in some cases endcard strips the videojs custom controls off the video and replaces them with native controls. Examples...

- Classic videojs video, with basic videojs styling - http://www.casedasole.it/video/endcard/index.html
- Same video plus endcard demo (at the end) - http://www.casedasole.it/video/endcard/2.html

**Please note:**

- Looks like it happens only on mobiles. On a PC, both videos have styled videojs controls in Chrome, FF and IE.
- It doesn't happen always on mobiles - there's no problem in Safari and Opera on iPad, but in Chrome on iPad, sometimes video 2 has videojs controls and then, on refresh, has native controls (when that happens, the video usually won't load).
- Where video 2 is always "native" is in Google Chrome developer tools (PC) - sometimes it looks OK, but after reload it's not. Using the developer tools I see that in the html of video 2 (the one with the endcard), the css class "vjs-using-native-controls" (which means display:none for the videojs controls) is being added to the video div. That isn't being added in the generated source in Firefox web developer.

I've tested the two files to see what may be causing this and have boiled it down to the javascript at the end of the html in [**video 2**](http://www.casedasole.it/video/endcard/2.html). If I delete it, the player gets its styled controls back in Chrome (iPad) and Chrome developer tools.

Hmm, maybe the problem is Chrome? Anyway, does anyone have some idea where the conflict arises, why only on mobiles, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the plugin, but rather the different way the player is initialised on the second page. Player options can be passed as the second argument to the `videojs` function:

```
var video = videojs('video', {"nativeControlsForTouch": false} );
```

Comment: Have I inserted that in the right place? - please see line 15 here: http://www.casedasole.it/video/endcard/fix.html  ...When I first load that page in Chrome on iPad  it has videojs controls, but on reload it sometimes, not always, goes "native". In Chrome developer tools (PC), always styled on first load, always native on reload.